# How to format the data within my dataset in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with some file names and sized and I would like to normalize the sizes for all rows to same unit (Mb):

This is my original data:

```
  filename  size
1        A 100Kb
2        B 200Kb
3        C  30Kb
4        D   1Mb
5        E  10Mb
```

This is what I am looking for (normalize the size to Mb):

```
  filename  size (Mb)
1        A        0.1
2        B        0.2
3        C       0.03
4        D          1
5        E         10
```

This is my original data frame:

```
df=rbind(c("3/22/2016", "2:36:41 PM", "3.1Kb", "HiSeqControlSoftware.Options.cfg", "character(0)"),
c("3/22/2016", "2:36:41 PM", "32.7Kb", "Variability_HiSeq_E.bin", "character(0)"),
c("3/22/2016", "2:36:42 PM", "character(0)", "Variability_HiSeq_E.bin", "74"),
c("3/22/2016", "2:36:42 PM", "character(0)", "HiSeqControlSoftware.Options.cfg", "76"),
c("3/22/2016", "2:36:42 PM", "20Kb", "HK7N2CCXX.xml", "character(0)"),
c("3/22/2016", "2:36:42 PM", "character(0)", "HK7N2CCXX.xml", "26"),
c("3/22/2016", "2:36:42 PM", "9.4Kb", "runParameters.xml", "character(0)"))
df = as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df) = c("date","timestamp","filesize","filename","time")
```

How would I do this?

thank you

Comment: <snarky>Before we write all of your code for you</snarky>, it would be helpful (and courteous) to show what code you've already tried, and how it isn't working. It might include `grepl`, `gsub`, `regexpr`, and/or perhaps a slew of `ifelse`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gsubfn` to do replace the non-numeric substring in the 'size' with `''` and `/1e3` and then use `eval(parse` to get the expected output.

```
library(gsubfn)
unname(sapply(gsubfn('[A-Za-z]+', list(Mb='', Kb = '/1e3'), 
    as.character(df$size)), function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))
#[1]  0.10  0.20  0.03  1.00 10.00
```

---

Or with `sub` from `base R` by replacing the numeric substring in 'size', match it with a key/value vector (`setNames(c(1/1e3, 1), c("Kb", "Mb"))` and multiply with the numeric part of 'size' by removing the non-numeric characters with `sub` (`sub("\\D+", "", df$size)`).

```
df$size_Mb <- (setNames(c(1/1e3, 1), c("Kb", "Mb")) [sub("\\d+", "", 
   df$size)]) * as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", df$size))
df$size_Mb
#[1]  0.10  0.20  0.03  1.00 10.00
```

---

**Update**

For the new dataset

```
 v1 <- setNames(c(1/1e3, 1), c("Kb", "Mb"))
 v1[sub("[^[:alpha:]]+", "", df$filesize)]*
       as.numeric(sub("[[:alpha:]]+", "", df$filesize))
 #    Kb     Kb   <NA>   <NA>     Kb   <NA>     Kb 
 #0.0031 0.0327     NA     NA 0.0200     NA 0.0094
```

Comment: how would you do that if we had decimal values?

Comment: @ManuelSopenaBallesteros  The first option I think still work for that.  In the second option.  You have to replace the `sub("\\d+", "", df$size)` with `sub('[0-9.]+', '', df$size)`

Comment: first option works fine, but it is too slow, I believe that eval is a killer, the second option doesn't work with decimals ... I tried df$size_Mb <- (setNames(c(1/1e3, 1, 1000), c("Kb", "Mb","Gb")) [sub("\\[0-9.]+", "", 
   df$size)]) * as.numeric(sub("\\[0-9.]+", "", df$size)) and also df$size_Mb <- (setNames(c(1/1e3, 1, 1000), c("Kb", "Mb","Gb")) [sub("\\[0-9.]+", "", 
   df$size)]) * as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", df$size))

Comment: @ManuelSopenaBallesteros  Can you update your post with an example data to test.

Answer (score 2):

There are options, but you need to chop the character strings into the numeric part and the label part. One option which assumes you *only* have `Mb` and `Kb` (but could be extended) is using `substr`:

```
df$size <- as.character(df$size)

df$size <- ifelse(substr(df$size, nchar(df$size)-1, nchar(df$size)) == 'Mb',
                  as.numeric(substr(df$size, 1, nchar(df$size)-2)),
                  as.numeric(substr(df$size, 1, nchar(df$size)-2))/1000)

names(df)[2] <- 'size_Mb'
df
#   filename size_Mb
# 1        A    0.10
# 2        B    0.20
# 3        C    0.03
# 4        D    1.00
# 5        E   10.00
```

`tidyr::separate` can also replace all the `substr` by separating `size` into two columns, simplifying the code a lot:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- separate(df, size, c('size', 'label'), sep = -3, convert = TRUE)
df$size_Mb <- ifelse(df$label == 'Mb', df$size, df$size/1000)
df <- df[,c('filename', 'size_Mb')]
```

If you combine `tidyr` and `dplyr`, you can do it all in one chain, if you like:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% separate(size, c('size', 'label'), sep = -3, convert = TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(size = ifelse(label == 'Mb', size, size/1000)) %>% 
    select(-label)
```

If you'd rather, you can separate with regex with something like

```
df$label <- sub('\\d+(\\w+)', '\\1', df$size)
df$size <- as.numeric(sub('(\\d+)\\w+', '\\1', df$size))
```